# Is lossy compression just downsizing?

Tags: image, algorithm, compression

I am interested in learning about compression and pixelation detection algorithms. While scouring the web I stumbled across downsizing and was wondering if that is all that lossy compression algorithms do, or is there more to it. More formally:

Is lossy compression strictly equivalent to downsizing, or is it downsizing plus some other stuff?

Comment: Lossy compression usually has nothing to do with downsizing. You could start by learning about the [JPEG codec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#JPEG_codec_example).

Comment: I am not putting this as an answer, but I think lossy compression is memory-efficient encoding that fails to be one-to-one, and downsizing is a fancy terminology for cutting things away.

Comment: Depending on your background, [Glicbawls](http://www.ioccc.org/2000/bmeyer.c) might be easier to understand than JPEG.  No cosine transforms or anything.  You predict the next pixel, figure out how wrong your prediction is, figure out how much you care, and entropy-code the result.  (Maybe read the `.hint` and/or the paper if the code isn't your thing.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't even have to be downsizing.

If you have an image with three or four pixels in a row that are a slightly different shade of blue (different by one bit, for instance), a lossy compression convert those all to the same color.

I did a Google Image search for "lossy image compression" and found this picture which is worth at least 100 words:

http://www.exposureguide.com/images/file-formats/jpeg-compression.jpg

MP3 compression, on the other hand, works by trying to figure out what parts of the sound you won't notice if is missing.  In complex music, on a good system, it isn't too hard to tell the difference between a lossy MP3 and a lossless OGG or WAV.

Comment: Ironic that your example image is also a JPEG, and imposes its own artifacts on the images it's trying to portray.

Comment: Sometime Ironic happens to just fall out of lazy. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean downsampling, subsampling, or decimation, as an example, removing every other pixel, then no, that is not all it is, nor is it necessary at all.

Image compression depends on the psycho-visual limitations of human perception in removing information from images that is either not perceptible or not important.  (Same thing for sound, taking advantage of psycho-acoustic limitations.)  If you push the compression too far, it will definitely be perceptible as artifacts, such as being able to perceive the boundaries of the 8x8 blocks that JPEG operates on, or the 16x16 blocks for MPEG-2.

JPEG does do subsampling, but only on the chroma channels.  RGB is converted to YUV, and the U and V components are subsampled, but the Y is left at full resolution.  This is a good example of the psycho-visual thing, where the human eye has far more rods than cones, where the rods measure intensity but not color, and the cones are use to fill in color.

JPEG and other image compression approaches convert the channels to the frequency domain to allow selective quantization (dropping lower significant bits) or deletion of higher frequency components.  This does not require any downsampling, and much of the compression of JPEG comes from this.

That's all lossy.  There is always a final lossless step that takes advantage of small values, strings of zeros, and so on, using run-length encoding, Huffman coding, and possibly more advanced entropy-coding techniques.